# Adding number_to_currency to amount in a message (part of a twilio service)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am using the following method in a service (sms notification via. twilio), and I would like to add number_to_currency to the message so the amount is formatted nicely. I have tried a few approaches, but I cannot seem to get it to work. Any thoughts?

**My method looks like this:**

```
def message(details)
  "A transaction of #{details[:amount]} was processed."
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can use [`NumberHelper#number_to_currency`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency)

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

def message(details)
  "A transaction of #{number_to_currency(details[:amount])} was processed."
end
```

It will use current locale, but you can specify it and also format output with these options

> `:locale` - Sets the locale to be used for formatting (defaults to current locale).
>
> `:precision` - Sets the level of precision (defaults to 2).
>
> `:unit` - Sets the denomination of the currency (defaults to “$”).
>
> `:separator` - Sets the separator between the units (defaults to “.”).
>
> `:delimiter` - Sets the thousands delimiter (defaults to “,”).
>
> `:format` - Sets the format for non-negative numbers (defaults to “%u%n”). Fields are `%u` for the currency, and `%n` for the number.
>
> `:negative_format` - Sets the format for negative numbers (defaults to prepending a hyphen to the formatted number given by `:format`). Accepts the same fields than `:format`, except `%n` is here the absolute value of the number.
>
> `:raise` - If true, raises `InvalidNumberError` when the argument is invalid.
>
> `:strip_insignificant_zeros` - If `true` removes insignificant zeros after the decimal separator (defaults to `false`).

Comment: My issue was that I was not including the actionview helper at the top. For some reason I thought I had access to that already. Thank you!